# Placing an image in side menu (Ionic)

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to place a profile pic retrieved from Facebook in the side menu like so:

[image]

But I am not having a lot of luck.

My code for the side menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark custom-header">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive custom-header">
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="custom-sidemenu">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="custom-item-nav" menu-close href="#/app/home">
          Home
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="custom-item-nav"  menu-close href="#/app/recepten">
          Recepten
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="custom-item-nav"  menu-close href="#/app/perfect-gin">
          The Perfect Gin Tonic Mix
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="custom-item-nav"  menu-close href="#/app/favorieten">
          Favorieten
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="custom-item-nav"  menu-close href="#/app/contact">
          Contacteer ons
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

I guess I am not sure where to place my div with the image in it.

Code of my div:

```
<div class="profile_frame_container">
        <img class="profile_frame" src="/img/profile_frame.png" alt="">
        <img class="profile_pic_fb" src="http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXX/picture?type=large" alt="">
    </div>
```

Comment: Post the full html and css please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [item-avatar](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-avatars) CSS class. For example place it in the `<ion-side-menu>`, inside `<ion-content><ul class="list">`:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
          </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
      </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content> 

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
        <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ul class="list">
          <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img src="//ionicframework.com/img/docs/spengler.jpg">
            <h2>Pretty Hate Machine</h2>
            <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#/event/check-in" class="item icon-left ion-home" menu-close>Home</a>
          <a href="#/event/attendees" class="item icon ion-person-stalker" menu-close>Friends</a>
          <a href="#/event/prices" class="item icon ion-star" menu-close>Prices</a>
        </ul>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
```

Here is a working example:

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/obGQXV

Answer (score 10):

For >ionic2

```
<ion-card text-center class="hide-card">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="custom-avatar"/>
    <h2>Victorcodex</h2>
    <p>Have some p tag here</p>
    <p>I am the third guy inline here</p>
    <hr>
</ion-card>

.hide-card {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
}

.custom-avatar {
  height: 30vw;
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image: ionic2-side-menu-centered-image-text]

Do lemme know if this was useful.